# Save session data in a folder

Tags: mediawiki

I am using Mediawiki 1.31.x to build a site on Windows 10 Professional. I need to save the session data in a local folder. In php.ini, I have the following:

```
session.save_path = "C:/session_data"
```

In Apache's http.conf, I have the following:

```
php_value session.save_path "C:/session_data"
```

However, Mediawiki does not save any data there. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I put `info.php` in the root directory of MW. It just has `phpinfo()`. Running this file shows the correct php.ini file. Am I doing this right? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer MediaWiki versions don't store sessions with the php session.save_path, instead they try to put them in objectcaches and the DB https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSessionCacheType